# Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java

Tags: java, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

> Connection to the layout rendere failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java

When i tried to run Xamarin and start developing app, opening layout files  gives me the error:

[image]

[Xamarin misconfiguration of java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDwGd.png)

Answer (score 7):

Gone through a few articles and I found a solution as most users said that it worked for them.

Anyway, try this:

1. *Uninstall* **Java JDK 1.6** and **Java JDK 1.7** using the "*Programs and Features*" control panel. On Windows, **Xamarin** will automatically pick version 1.6 or 1.7 instead of version 1.8 if either of those older versions are installed.
2. *Install* the **Java JDK 1.8** *(64-bit)*

Comment: this worked for me perfectly.  I also found out that you have to keep the emulator OPEN for this to work.   After each run of the program, on the emulator you have to REMOVE / uninstall the app.  Then, run your app again and it will work!

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue with a new Visual Studio 2017.
VS was referencing the 64bit JDK instead of the 32bit one.

Just go to

```
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings
```

and change to point to the x86 JDK which is in

```
Program Files (x86)\Java
```

rather than

```
Program Files\Java.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your Java installation to ensure that mets Xamarin's requirements. Following the information below to ensure that at least Java 1.7 is properly installed.

**Note**: If 1.7 is installed correctly and in the correct location and it is still not working, you can try upgrading to Java 1.8 as that appears to have solved this problem on others setups.

---

[Installing the Java SDK (JDK)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_the_Java_SDK_JDK)

> It is essential to install the 32-bit version of the Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that v1.7 of the Java JDK is installed (although it is fine to have 1.8 or newer installed at the same time).
>
> It is recommend that the Java JDK is placed in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Java. This is the default location, and is where your IDE will check to see if it is installed.

---

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

uninstall xamarin, android sdk and all java JDK after reinstall xamarin installer will fix this headache

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here worked for me. I'm running Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2 at the moment and I was getting the same error. I tried installing x32 bit version of JDK 11, and that didn't help.

What worked finally, after going through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk, was to change the path to Java Development Kit Location (Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings) to C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your Xamarin Studio. I got mine fixed by doing this

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Android SDK. You can do this by downloading the recent version. If you already have installed Android Studio, the Android SDK will be installed. So after Downloading copy the `tools` folder and paste it to

```
c:\users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```