# how to fix xamarin android layout renderer failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by misconfiguration of Java"

When i tried to run Xamarin and start developing app, opening layout files gives me the error:

```
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect  at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
> java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
> java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
> java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)   at
> java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)   at
> mono.android.HostProcessConnection.Connect(HostProcessConnection.java:23)
>   at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.run(AndroidDesignerHost.java:54)
>   at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.main(AndroidDesignerHost.java:43)
```

[image: JDK Path]

[image: xamarin android java misconfiguration connection exception]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: xamarin android layout rendering problem. don't show layout designer. its give this exception.

Comment: xamarin android java misconfiguration. but my JDK setup correctly. I also try using 32-bit JDK. it's also same problem

Comment: @DonaldDuck i am already added a screnshot of my visual studio project

Comment: @​AHRaselAhamed Please [edit] your question to include that information. I also recommend you read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [edit] your question accordingly to get better answers.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks for your time. going to edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231060/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-this-may-be-caused-by-misconfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. it was the problem with Android SDK. 
after the update, Android SDK to latest version problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check if your JDK and your JRE are of the same Version if not that could be the reason for this problem

You can find your JRE in your JDK folder

Comment: Both are same version. I am also trying with different versions. But didn't fixed this problem.

Comment: try updating the android sdk to its latest version then @AHRaselAhamed       Also check if you have other verisons of jdk in the same folder in case you do maintain the latest version or your preferred jdk version.

Comment: And if that doesnt work
Jusy Copy AndroidDesigner.jar

from
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\java\AndroidDesigner.jar"

to
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android\4.7.04014\java\AndroidDesigner.jar"

Comment: Thank you for your time. I&#39;m going to update my Android SDK. But i have questions why xamarin or visual studio don't gives us proper error instructions. If problem wit sdk or jdk it gives us same massage. And thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: Well actually the problem is its very difficult to determine which of the above is causing the problem that's all anyways do try the workaround and let me know what happens!. @AHRaselAhamed